# IONIC google map showing white screen

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I cant show google map on device

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {
  GoogleMaps,
  GoogleMap,
  GoogleMapsEvent,
  GoogleMapOptions,
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  map: GoogleMap;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap() {
    let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
      camera: {
        target: {
          lat: 43.0741904,
          lng: -89.3809802
        },
        zoom: 18,
        tilt: 30
      }
    };

    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', mapOptions);

    // Wait the MAP_READY before using any methods.
    this.map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Map is ready!');

        // Now you can use all methods safely.
        this.map.addMarker({
          title: 'Ionic',
          icon: 'blue',
          animation: 'DROP',
          position: {
            lat: 43.0741904,
            lng: -89.3809802
          }
        })
          .then(marker => {
            marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK)
              .subscribe(() => {
                alert('clicked');
              });
          });

      });
  }

}
```

With this css and html

```
page-home {
  #map_canvas{
    height: 400px;
  }
}
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <div #map_canvas></div>
</ion-content>
```

Im going to run on android device, which is connected to my PC via USB and with this command

```
ionic cordova run -l -c -s --debug
```

And it gave me this error

```
[23:26:34]  console.warn: Native: tried accessing the GoogleMaps plugin but Cordova is not available. Make sure to 
            include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
```

Its a new project i just want to try ionic, im new in it, and wanted to add google map to app. I have google maps API enabled in console, also on device app refreshing, but map not showing up.

Thank you for anything

Comment: did you try to run it on emulator or device

Comment: Have u included the api key in the ionic app

Comment: Make sure the plugin is present in the _plugins_ folder. Remove the platform, then add again. After that, try to run the following command: **ionic cordova run android**

Comment: @Amr.Ayoub yes tried :(

Comment: @PetrusCyrino i tried removing and adding it back three times, nothing changed. Currently solved it with different google maps plugin, not for cordova but for angular, but it works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the multiple_maps branch version.

```
$> git clone https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps

$> git checkout multiple_maps

$> git pull

$> cd (project dir)

$> cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-googlemaps

$> cordova plugin add (path to)/cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="..." --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="..." 
```